# Angular 4 , How Convert Number to Word in English and Arabic

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router, angular-directive

I'm trying when user enter amount number display the number in word English and arabic

there are plugin support this in English and Arabic ?

For Example :
1980 :One thousand, nine hundred eighty.

1980 :الف وتسعمائة وثمانون .

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: Can you explain ? there example ?

Comment: just google for it

Comment: i didn't find any javascript support arabic numbers

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here you go

This should be self explanatory. It gets the current date, formats it. You can toggle between English and Arabic.

*Note that I do not speak Arabic, but the `ar` locale is used to provided the formatting. Therefore, I included Chinese as well for good measure since I know a little.*

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>The current date and time using locale: {{locale}}</h1>
<p>Now: {{now | date : 'full' : '' : locale}}</p>
<button (click)="toggleLocale()">Toggle Locale</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export default class {
  constructor(@Inject('registered-locales') readonly locales: string[]) {}

  get now() {return new Date();}

  val = 19.8;

  locale = this.locales[0];

  toggleLocale() {
    // this is just a cycler. There are better ways to right this code
    const predicate = this.locale && this.locale.match(/zh/)
      ? l => l.match('ar')
      : this.locale && this.locale.match(/en/)
      ? l => l.match('zh')
      : l => l.match('en');

    this.locale = this.locales.find(predicate);
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import arabic from '@angular/common/locales/ar';
import chinese from '@angular/common/locales/zh';
import english from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import {registerLocaleData} from '@angular/common';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import AppComponent from './app.component';

registerLocaleData(arabic, 'ar');
registerLocaleData(chinese, 'zh');
registerLocaleData(english, 'en');

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: 'registered-locales', multi: true, useValue: 'ar'},
    {provide: 'registered-locales', multi: true, useValue: 'zh'},
    {provide: 'registered-locales', multi: true, useValue: 'en'}
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) export default class { }
```

And just so you cannot complain about type errors or anything like that, here is

**main.ts**

```
import 'core-js';
import 'zone.js';
import {NgModuleRef} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import AppModule from './app/app.module';

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();

(async function () {
  try {
    const ref = await platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
    const {ngRef} = window;
    if (ngRef) {
      ngRef.destroy();
    }
    window.ngRef = ref;
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}());

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ngRef: NgModuleRef<AppModule>;
  }
}
```

[Here is a live, editable example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gasts1?embed=1&file=main.ts) of the very same code running

Comment: Please see another shorter solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24594535/convert-arabic-numbers-to-words-with-javascript/71356825#71356825